# How do we override ActiveRecord::Migration class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration

I just wants to override the base migration class by adding some attribute in it.
e.g.: for the purpose of soft delete, I wants whenever I generate a new migration using "rails g migration", **is_deleted** column always be there.
So the point is where we can define this **is_deleted** column as default column, to avoid re-writing it in each migration?

Comment: I would start by here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html